# Right Click ContextMenu event firing multiple times

Tags: openlayers

I've a code snippet like below:

```
map.getViewport().addEventListener('contextmenu', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(e.x);
            openContextMenu(e.x, e.y);
        });
```

basically I am trying to add contextmenu to the openlayer map. But a weird behavior is happening. When I right click, the event listener gets raised multiple no. of times. i.e. in the above code, console.log would print more than 30 times for just one right click on the map.

Now if I handle this by using a flag, then context menu doesn't get rendered i.e. looks like openlayer needs all those multiple calls. 
But since I intend to do complex operations on the listener, I can't have it get called multiple times when right clicked just once.

how do I resolve this? Is there any other better way of adding right click context menus to openlayer map

I am using openlayer 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet works for me and the event fires only once. Could it be that this snippet is within a context that's being executed multiple times on your page? In other words, is the event listener being added more than once? If so, OpenLayers will register each listener separately even though they're identical, and you'll end up with them all firing when you click.

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving this message for those who will write javascript after us. I had the same issue with a script that changed the right click event of all elements. and I solved the problem just by defining the oncontextmenu event on the window element. The clicked element can be found with the event target sent to the event function.